# Does youtube v3 Data api have a limit to the number of id's you can send to videos.list?

Tags: javascript, api, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I want to get the total playtime of a youtube playlist, so first I request video id's for each element in a playlist then I request the durations for all the videos.

There is a limit to how many items the playlist returns, which is 50, so I have to make multiple requests until I get to the end of the playlist.

[Youtube's Data API v3 Docs entry for /videos/list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) say that in the `id` parameter to the api you can list multiple video id's, and that `pageToken` "is not supported for use in conjunction with the id parameter". So I should be able to send more than 50 id's to get the entire collection back, but when I do I get a 400 response with the message "The request specifies an invalid filter parameter" ("invalidFilters").

Is there a limit to the number of id's you can send? If so, what is it?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The limit is 50 ids. You have to make a request to `/videos` per playlist page, you can't just have one gigantic request.

Comment: can you point to some doc? cant find this '50' limit. https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list

Comment: @EyalCh it seems to be an arbitrary limit. I did not find any documentation for it either, and discovered this limit through trial and error.

Comment: Came across this comments, and well it's quite hidden but its documented: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list under "maxResults" => Acceptable values are 1 to 50, inclusive. The default value is 5.

Well you can't submit 51 ids when you only can retrieve 50.

Comment: @Nightking Currently it says that "maxResults => ... is not supported for use in conjunction with the id parameter", so that limit doesn't apply to ids. And it looks like limit for ids is not documented anywhere.

Comment: @MarkusLaire Of course maxResults cannot be used when you're using the id parameter, because they are exact opposite parameters. The point is: if the limit for returned items is 50 at a time, it makes sense that the limit for input items is also 50 at a time. It's not documented, but it's a common sense inference and it seems to apply.

Comment: Also, as others have mentioned, this is the limit found through trial and error.  You can't just make a single gigantic request, you have to do the work in chunks of 50.